# Are there thread group-local variables in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am looking for a class similar to ThreadLocal which would work on thread groups instead of threads.

If there is not such a class (in some open source library) how would you implement it? Some better idea than having thread groups in WeakHashMap?

I am implementing a debugging framework tunable in run-time with various parameters in global, per-thread and per-thread group contexts. As a very simple example, you can have a reporting statement:

```
debug.log( category, message);
```

and specify that the log entry with that specific category will be displayed only when called by a thread in group of threads servicing network requests.

Comment: For clarities sake you might want to throw some usage examples up.  Also why/how you want to do this.

Comment: @Kevin: Just added a motivation and a simple example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would store a value holder in a thread local and initialize it to the same value holder for all threads of the same group.

```
 public class ThreadGroupLocal<T> extends ThreadLocal<ValueHolder> {
     private static class ValueHolder {
         public Object value;
     }
     // Weak & Concurrent would be even the better, but Java API wont offer that :(
     private static ConcurrentMap<ThreadGroup, ValueHolder> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<ThreadGroup, ValueHolder>;
     private static ValueHolder valueHolderForThread(Thread t) {
         map.putIfAbsent(t.getThreadGroup(), new ValueHolder());
         return map.get(t.getThreadGroup());
     }
     @Override 
     protected ValueHolder initialValue() {
         return valueHolderForThread(Thread.currentThread());
     }
     public T getValue() { (T) get().value; }
     public void setValue(T value) { get().value = value; }
 }
```

and then use

```
 ThreadGroupLocal<String> groupLocal = new ThreadGroupLocal<String>();
 groupLocal.setValue("foo");
 //...
 String foo = groupLocal.getValue();
```

That does (expect for the initialization) perform exactly like a thread local.

Comment: Why didn't you generify ValueHolder? And why did you make it extend ThreadLocal? The use of ThreadLocal<ValueHolder> is an implementation detail.

Comment: Good points, they are worth being considered. I wrote that code in a hurry as proof-of-concept, so please review (and test!!!) it before using it in production. (PS: *I recall now why ValueHolder is not generified, because they are stored in a static hash map that would degenerate to `<?>` so you need to cast anyway.*)

Comment: +1, Just what I was looking for. Do you know if in nowadays Java API natively supports this feature ?

Comment: @dreamcrash I haven’t used Java since.

Comment: (Note, if you were doing this in a context with mobile code, you'd need to deal with malicious subclasses of `ThreadGroup`, and you'd not want to leak when a `ThreadGroup` become unreachable. You may also want the `ThreadGroup` to be able to become unreachable even when reachable by its own `ThreadGroupLocal` values, which is fun.)

Answer (score 5):

`ThreadGroup` is rarely used, so there isn't platform support.

Using [`Weak`/`Identity`/`Concurrent`]`HashMap<ThreadGroup,T>` will just about work, if not very fast. You really want the map to be all weak, identity and concurrent but with the Java library you only get to choose one, currently.

To improve performance, note that `Thread`s do not change `ThreadGroup`. Therefore, cache the value with a `ThreadLocal` (override `initialValue`). `ThreadLocal` has good performance (a couple dozen cycles per `get`).

Comment: +1, for the performance issues. Do you know if in nowadays Java API natively supports this feature ?

Answer (score 2):

The last time i looked at the implementation (well a few years ago) Thread Locals were implemented as a simple hash table indexed by the thread id. Nothing fancy and miles away from the efficiency of C++.

You can do the same and use the thread group object as a key for your own thread group locals hash table.

Comment: Even (Sun) 1.2 has been updated not to do that. It's very inefficient.

Comment: Yes i know it was a long time ago.

Comment: I think it is now a hash table inside of the Thread instance, indexed by ThreadLocal object. This removes synchronization overhead, one private hash table per thread.